# Как из текстого документа вытащить определенную строку?

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл, где с новый строчки записаны ну допустим id, и мне нужно в вытащить именно вторую строчку из этого документа и вывести ее, как это реализовать ?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример файла.

Comment: В чём затруднение? Вы не умеете читать файлы? Не умеете работать со строками? Покажите вашу попытку решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[1])  # вывести вторую строку файла
```